The Rebbe Rashab and the Lubavitcher Rebbe's Position on the Three Oaths
B"H
I'm trying to properly understand the Lubavitcher Rebbe's view on Zionism and the land of Yisroel, but I'm having a hard time getting authoritative answers.
I heard that the Rebbe RaSha"B spoke out very harshly against early Zionism, specifically by signing his name on the letter "Ohr layasharim," which said that we should do everything possible to oppose it and protest against it, etc. He made his position clear in further writings and addresses. I believe that the Rebbe RaSha"B also said that it violates the Three Oaths, although I haven't been able to confirm the exact wording.
Obviously the Rebbe supported the land of Yisroel and defending the Jewish people living there at all costs, etc; he had many sichos about telling the world that it's our land, because Hashem gave it to us and references the first Rashi.
But what is the difference between the two views? Surely, the Rebbe wouldn't have contradicted what the Rebbe RaShaB said.
Also, regarding the Rebbe's more recent position about being firm with our claim to the land because of it's G-d given nature, is that itself enough of a reason to establish the state initially, or was that used only as the main claim specifically after it was established?
To the best of my knowledge, there are many anti zionist rabbis who use the Rebbe Rashab's words (amongst other things) to justify openly protesting against and opposing the modern day state of Yisroel. Why is there a difference if opinion between the Rebbe and these other rabbis in this matter?

Maybe Ohr Layesharim

R' Yoel Kahn wrote about it in מענה חכם

Might be useful info in this recent book https://www.amazon.com/dp/1938163400

The Erlauer Rav זצ"ל changed his view in light of the establishment of the State. While he remained non-Zionist, he held that the metziut changed when Medinat Yisrael was established. I've heard that the Rayatz of Lubavitch also conceded this sea change

The Rebbe rashab and the Rebbe both lived in very different times and responded to the times they lived in. The Rebbe rashab did not live when the state of Israel existed and sought to prevent it from happening while the lubavitcher Rebbe lived after the state was already in existence and wanted the best outcomes for the Jewish people living there

@dude yes I hear, but there are some people who use the rebbe rashab 's words to openly oppose the modern state, why is there a difference between those opinions and the Rebbe?

Reread and understand my comment and you'll know

@Dude I read it. All it said was that the Rebbe rashab was before the state was established and the Rebbe was after. But why is that a difference in philosophy, if it's bad before shouldn't it still be bad?

Life is more complex than that. Destroying Israel would put millions of Jews in danger and having a strong Israel is important to the safety and security of Jews living within ererz Yisroel and around the world. Once the state was created yes things changed because it was already done and we cannot go back in time. This is a fruitless discussion. More important is influencing our fellow Jews to keep Torah and mitzvos rather than a theoretical discussion about what might have been best in the past that cannot be now

@Dude I'm just trying to understand both sides, why can't the Jews theoretically immigrate to other countries? It seems like the lubavitcher Rebbe specifically wanted the Jews to stay in Yisroel and settle it under the understanding that this is our G-d given land. But is that different than the Rebbe rashab?

@B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem there is no both sides. The Rebbe is a continuation from the previous rebbeim before him. Both responses fit the circumstances in which they happened

@dude I know, I'm talking about the sides that falsely use the Rebbe rashab's words to denounce the current Israeli government. What is fundamentally different now?

Rabbi Yosef Yitzchok Schneersohn, the Lubavitcher Rebbe (1880-1950) wrote a fiery pamphlet, saying:

When a devout Jew arrives at one of these places, with the calming of his worldly worries and the inspiration of Israel's great leaders, he builds yet another institution: a Torah study room, a yeshiva, a house of kindness and charity. As stated, one of us is exiled to Barbary and another to Britain, etc., and we must have complete faith and recognize with clear understanding that when the righteous Messiah comes—speedily in our days—it will be preferable in his and G-d’s eyes to have a study hall or a house of charity founded in the exile in Barbary or Britain than a factory or a workplace established—Heaven forbid—in Jerusalem, the Holy City. (Tikun Olam, siman 41)

In Ohr Layesharim (p. 59) (quoted by RabbiKaii), the Rebbe Rashab is quoted in saying that:

Those who assist these aforementioned Zionists are destined to be held accountable, for they strengthen the hands of those who cause the multitudes to sin. Therefore, whoever is for G-d and His Torah should not associate with evildoers nor cling to them. On the contrary, they should oppose them in every possible way. Until the will of God redeems us, we must accept the yoke of exile to atone for our sins. We must strengthen ourselves to stand firm against every wave, being courageous and resolute in observing the Torah and mitzvot. This is what God demands of us, and we must hope to Him, for His salvation is near, and our righteous Messiah will come speedily in our days, Amen. Even if he tarries, wait for him, for the matter depends on us rectifying our deeds. May the Holy One, Blessed be He, have mercy upon us and hasten our redemption speedily in our days, Amen.

He gives three points:


As for the argument of the Zionists: "Why don't the God-fearing and devout stand at the head of the movement?"

How can the G-d-fearing stand at the head of a movement that opposes
the core of our belief in the true redemption, as mentioned above?

The G-d-fearing cannot collaborate with them because they (the Zionists) will not heed the words of the devout in matters of religion
and education. They will act in their strange ways, according to the
freedom deeply rooted in their hearts, and they will even dare to
claim that the devout agree with them. Many of the Jewish masses, in
their simplicity, will believe that all their actions are endorsed by
the devout and G-d-fearing. Later, if the devout withdraw from them
and cry out against them (even if they make their voices heard in the
press), their withdrawal will not have as much impact.

Their prior collaboration will overshadow their later separation. This is what we see now with some of their great leaders who have
withdrawn from the workers’ movement and oppose them, yet their
current opposition does not carry the weight that their earlier
involvement did.

In truth, they do not want the G-d-fearing to join them at all, because they know the devout will stand in their way and oppose their
chosen path of rebellion (to completely cast off the yoke of Torah and
mitzvos, turning Judaism solely into nationalism, as mentioned above).
At the Warsaw gatherings, when the rabbis demanded that a rabbinical
council also be included in the leadership, they refused entirely.
Their representatives—their writers—published articles in the press
mocking and insulting the rabbis, ridiculing them for daring to make
such a demand, using disrespectful language. From this, it is evident
that they do not want the involvement of the G-d-fearing, as it would
hinder their wicked plans. May G-d thwart their counsel and raise the
dignity of the Jewish people.



For further reading, check this out!

Hi thanks but the main point of the question is the most recent Lubavitcher Rebbe's support for it, surely he wouldn't contradict things that his predecessors said

I suppose the question is also whether the Zionism and the state at the time the Rebbe "supported" it was the same as when the Rebbe Rashab wrote against it, and I think the answer is very much not.

@B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem that's a separate question, and has been asked here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/142468/what-was-the-lubavitcher-rebbes-position-on-zionism/142469?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C20.3596#142469

@RabbiKaii that answer references what the Rebbe rashab claimed but didn't give sources for the most recent Lubavitcher Rebbe's difference of opinion. Also the question doesn't ask to contrast the Rebbe rashab and the Rebbe's positions

@B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem "the main point of the question is the most recent Lubavitcher Rebbe's support for it, surely he wouldn't contradict things that his predecessors said" is pretty much what the other question is asking, so if you are saying that this question is not exactly as stated in the OP, then it's better you clarify that ASAP before you get more incorrect answers. You might consider adding a bounty to the other question too

@RabbiKaii the other question doesn't mention the Rebbe rashaba at all
